# Install packages on a Ubuntu Virtual Machine that has no Internet connection nor GUI?

Tags: networking, apt, software-installation

I've been given an Ubuntu VM to work with. It has no internet connection nor GUI. Actually, it's not supposed to be used directly, but I need some extra libraries on it and I don't know how to install them. My idea is to download the libraries somewhere else, copy them through WinSCP and install them throw PuTTY. This should replace the `apt-get install`. The problem is that I don't know where to download them. If you know how to do that I would really appreciate. If you have any other idea that can solve this problem it's also fine. Thank you.

**EDIT: RELEASE DETAILS**

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

```
hostnamectl
Static hostname: 06e2e468f8c4
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 07e8a1bebd223fc12a4a73e45d72352a
           Boot ID: ae8230cd752c4e5f8a4772ebf2ae80a1
    Virtualization: oracle
  Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-75-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

```
uname -srm
Linux 4.4.0-75-generic x86_64
```

Comment: You haven't provided release details, however `apt-get` won't install local files (the *get* part of the name is a clue, `apt` will, as well as `dpkg` will).  If you view your sources files anyway you'll get clue anyway.

Comment: I did not get your point. Antway now I edit with the release details

Answer (score 2):

Using `apt` or `dpkg` command will help you install the package. 
**How to install with apt** 
Open terminal and run

```
apt update
apt install package_name
```

**NB:** `apt`  requires internet connection.
**How to install with dpkg** 
Download the **.deb** from a safe source, change to the directory of your **.deb** files using `cd` command, run

```
dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

If there is more than one **.deb** file, your can make the installation with a regular expression by running

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```